# Google protobuf, match expected message size versus bytes received from network

Tags: python, deserialization, protocol-buffers, descriptor, nanopb

In order to test receiving and deserializing protobuf messages sent from a server I would like to check the received network bytes vs the expected size of a serialized fully populated message. There are some intermediate black-box steps and I want to check that the server sends the correct serialized message upon a request.
I already assured that the received bytes from the network is actually a serialized message, but it is not clear if it is the correct one.

Still two messages could have the same serialized size but it is a corner case and when I hit something like this, this would be part of some further step and I don't want to include it into this question.

I used `protoc` with the `--python_out dir` option to generate a `X_pb2.py` file containing the message definitions from `.proto` file.

I thought of the following possible (hacky) alternatives:

1.) Iterate over the `X_pb2.MY_Message().DESCRIPTOR.fields`, determine the field sizes from their individual sizes and sum them up to get the expected size of the fully populated message

2.) Iterate over the `X_pb2.MY_Message().DESCRIPTOR.fields`, determine the field types and initialize them randomly. Then just call `X_pb2.MY_Message().ByteSize()`

3.) Initialize a `X_pb2.MY_Message()`, serialize it and then get the `ByteSize()`

However, I stumbled over some problems:

1.) When trying this alternative, the calculated expected size of the serialized msg is smaller then the original msg, which is impossible. E.g. a message consisting of [int8_t, int32_t, uint32_t] has a serialized size of 5 whereas the sum of the datatype sizes is 9.
Code: `sum([x.GetOptions().ByteSize() for x in X_pb2.MY_Message().DESCRIPTOR.fields])`

2.) I did not found a generic way to set the fields value. It seems I can only set them via `MY_MESSAGE().fieldx = ...`, which is not suitable for generic access.

3.) Same as 2.)

Maybe you can help me find a solution so I can `assert expected_size == bytes_received_from_network`.

Comment: The question is tagged nanopb, but it appears you are not using nanopb? For nanopb specifically, you could use `MY_Message_size` define in the `.pb.h`, which is present if the nanopb generator has  enough information to calculate it. This is the maximum size, actual messages can be smaller because of variable length encoding.

Comment: In `C` it's clear. In python it seems not so easy to access this kind of metadata. I use `nanopb` in the sense, that the python package provides the `protoc` compiler to compile the `.proto` files a.o.t. into python modules.

Comment: This may help: https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/ . Also if you just want protoc, you can install `grpcio-tools` directly, it is the dependency of nanopb package where protoc actually comes from.